# Am I using the best service to deploy dockerized machine learning model api/microservice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, machine-learning, microservices, fastapi

Right now, I am pushing to ECR and then building a container in ECS. Everything works, finally figured out ssl the other day too.

But I am new to AWS and I am finding different articles/tutorials/etc on using things like beanstalk, ec2, lambda and then there is amazon API Gateway ...

Is my approach a viable one? Basically I am sending a screenshot of a live webcam as a base64 string from a reactjs front end (which is also deployed the same way I described at the top) and the processed image is returned as the post request response as base64 string. the response is sent to one of three Microservices deployed on ecs.

Is there a better way? do I need to do anything further? is the API Gateway relevant to me?

Comment: Is the image processing long? Seems like you have a blocking architecture, where client will wait hanging till processing is done and processed image is send back?

Comment: It definitely can be yes, and in some cases, pretty damn long.  But that is correct, the client sees a loading spinner until processed image is returned. Nothing is saved to disk/storage during the processed, the processing is done in memory

Comment: The blocking architecture is not a very scalable design. Its easy to implement, but in the long term can lead to issues, if your processing time further increase for instance. I would consider decoupling your architecture and process images asynchronously.

Comment: Interesting , thats a good point.  could you elaborate on what  decoupling and asynchronous image processing would look like?

do you mean I would have an api that takes request, sends image to be processed and the response is a 'job id' of sorts.  then the front end makes request to a db or something with that job id until it gets something back?

Comment: Yes, that would be better design IMO and you are fully decoupling front-end from the backend. It should lead to more scalable and easier to maintain architecture.